# Ionic3 staticInjectorError

Tags: ionic3

I need some help about staticinjector error  in ionic3 and firebase.

My problem is using AngularFireAuth in a page constructor. like this;

```
constructor(private windowSvc: WindowService,
public navCtrl: NavController,
public navParams: NavParams,
private autSvc: AuthenticationService,
private userSvc: UserService,
private angAuth: AngularFireAuth)
```

when i use angularfireAuth in constructor i always get this error message:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FirebaseApp -> InjectionToken FirebaseAppConfigToken]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FirebaseApp -> InjectionToken FirebaseAppConfigToken]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken FirebaseAppConfigToken!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FirebaseApp -> InjectionToken FirebaseAppConfigToken]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FirebaseApp -> InjectionToken FirebaseAppConfigToken]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken FirebaseAppConfigToken!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:1003)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10896)
    at _callFactory (core.js:10960)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10910)
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:1003)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10896)
    at _callFactory (core.js:10960)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10910)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.reject (polyfills.js:3)
    at NavControllerBase._fireError (nav-controller-base.js:223)
    at NavControllerBase._failed (nav-controller-base.js:216)
    at nav-controller-base.js:263
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4760)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1449
```

App.Module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrMaskerModule,
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireAuthModule, 
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
    AuthenticationService,
    UserService,
    WindowService,
    AngularFireAuth
  ]
})
```

what should i do to fix this error ?

Comment: Did you add it in *app.module.ts*  provider (*Firebase*)

Comment: yes i've added to app.module.ts providers
 @NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrMaskerModule,
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireAuthModule, 
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
    AuthenticationService,
    UserService,
    WindowService,
    AngularFireAuth
  ]
})

Comment: please give me your plugin `import { somthing } from "somewhere"

Comment: import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import firebase from 'firebase';
import { WindowService } from '../../services/window-service'


import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../../services/authentication';

import { UserService } from '../../services/user-service';

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { firebase } from 'firebase';

....
....
....
.

providers: [firebase]
....
....
```

```html
Look your file u use ` import firebase from 'firebase'` like this. please change it
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem its about module.ts (not app.module.ts). When you create a page make it with no module. If there is a page module it gives that error